# how to add featured product in right sidebar of magento

Tags: html, magento, e-commerce

I searched a lot but didn't work any tutorial for me. Please help me out in this issue

i want to show my featured products on right sidebar in Magento.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the below extension

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/featured-products-on-magento-frontpage/
Create local.xml under app/design/frontend/yourpackage/your template/layout

```
add the below code:
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="featuredproducts/listing" name="featuredproducts_sidebar" template="inchoo/featuredproducts/list.phtml" before="-" />
      </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```